# Prevent Serilog Gzip from corrupting log files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I tried modifying the Serilog configuration for my .NET 6 application to automatically write a compressed version of the log file. The relevant part is configured as following:

```
.WriteTo.File(
  new CompactJsonFormatter(), 
  "/somepath/log/json/main_log_.json",
  rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, 
  hooks: new GZipHooks())
```

I am flushing the logs when the application closes with the following code:

```
      try
      {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
      }
      finally
      {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
      }
```

I'm using the following versions of the Serilog libraries:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File.GZip" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Map" Version="1.0.2" />
```

What happens is that the log file is properly written the first time I start the application, but when I restart the application I get the following error message when trying to read the gzipped log file:

> invalid compressed data--format violated

I looked a bit closer and as far as I can tell the gzipped log file is never closed correctly, I get an "unexpected end of file" error when I look at the file after I close my application (but before starting it again). I also added some logging directly before the `Log.CloseAndFlush` call and it seems like this is not called when I stop the application in my development environment. So this is in the end my fault because I am shutting it down hard and don't let the flushing code run. But that is a situation that will also happen in real use sometimes, and it would be really annoying to have corrupt log files every time the app shuts down hard.

Am I missing something here, or is the gzip file sink only usable if you can guarantee that the application is shut down in an ordered fashion every time? Or did I configure something wrong here?

Is there any way to avoid this issue and still have compressed log files with Serilog?